# Editing a Form in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

I am working with **MS-Access** and I have created a Form(1) that consists of  data from a Query(1) and a subform with data from a Table(2). Along with that, I have the Form(1) in a Split Form View displaying the datasheet at the bottom. The problem I am having is that I want to be able to completely edit everything as well as **Add New Records**(main problem) in the Form but, Access is not allowing me too.   To understand my problem better, I have added some descriptions of the tables and attached some images below:

Table 1: Sales - 
   Fields: SalesID(AutoNumber), Customer(Short Text), and Date(Date/Time)

Table 2: Transaction -
   Fields: TransactionID(AutoNumber), SalesID(Number), Sales(Currency), Cost(Currency), and Profit(Calculated, Currency -> [Sales]-[Cost])

Relationship: Table 1: SalesID(one) -> Table 2: SalesID(many)

[Query 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdAO3.png)
[Form 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38JVU.png)

Comment: Access is not allowing you to edit what? Aggregate queries are not editable.

Comment: I wold like to add a new record, and I would like to add a new transaction which would update the aggregates

Comment: I tried taking the query and making it a table and then creating a form out of it but there were still problems with the sums

Answer (score 0):

I created a form/subform arrangement like you describe. No problem adding new record. However, getting the aggregate query to update requires code to requery the form's data. So in the subform's AfterUpdate event:

```
Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Me.Parent.Requery
End Sub
```

One drawback to this may be that focus will be returned to first record of the main form.

UPDATE: Learned something new - Me.Parent.Recordset.Requery will not return focus to first record.

Comment: "Me.Parent.Requery". Me and Parent are alias object variables (that's the best description I can think of) in VBA language library.

Comment: Since I cannot replicate the issue, will have to review your db. If you want to provide, I recommend Box.com fileshare site and post link to file.

Comment: I am not able to accept your answer because I have less than 15 reputation

Comment: Still having problems with adding a new customer. This is the link for the access file: https://app.box.com/s/ko67am9nlarwcah10mb1q10wyex4js3a

Comment: I am confused. I went to the New Record row of the subform and type data into Cost and Sales fields without any difficulty.

Comment: I mean like add a complete brand new customer in the parent form. For example, you would add a new customer named John and a date. Then you would add a new transaction record.

Comment: The parent form is bound to an aggregate query. Aggregate queries are not editable, therefore cannot add record. Will have to redesign form or open another form for 'Add New Customer'. What you have is very unconventional. 'Unconventional' means more difficult.